# Show that the linear operator $T_{B}:{\cal M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow {\cal M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ has determinant zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B\in {\cal M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and let $T_{B}$ the linear operator defined by $T_{B}(A)=AB-BA$. I need to show that it has determinant zero. To show that I exhibited a nonzero matrix $A$ such that $T_{B}(A)=0$, which is equivalent to show that $\ker(T_{B})\ne\{0\}$ and then $T_{B}$ is not invertible, which implies that it has determinant zero. The matrix that I exhibited was the identity matrix $I_{n}$. What I want to know if the argument is right. Thanks!.

Comment: That is correct. (Probably you found it already, but note that that there's a natural choice for $A$ such that $T_B(A) = 0$.)

Comment: Really??, a natural choice different from Identity matrix?

Comment: $B,B,B,B,..... $

Comment: :) :) Yeah! I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred No. In case $B$ is zero, it is not a non-trivial solution of $T_B(A)=0$. In contrast, $A=I$ is always a non-trivial solution regardless of the value of $B$.

Comment: I should have said *another. Of course, if $B = 0$, then any nonzero matrix will do. NB in general $\dim \ker T_B \leq n (n - 1)$.

Comment: @User 1551  if $B $ is zero  then the operator is zero,  hence has det 0.

Comment: @Fred Sure, but that makes $B$ a less natural choice than $I$, because you need a separate argument to deal with the corner case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is fine.

Another possibility is to show that $T_B$ is not surjective. That's so because, for each $A\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$,$$\operatorname{tr}\bigl(T_B(A)\bigr)=\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0.$$Therefore, for instance, $\operatorname{Id}_n\notin T_B\bigl(\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)\bigr)$.